# lucene FileNotFoundException when starting server

Tags: liferay, vaadin

I keep on getting FileNotFoundExceptions when starting Liferay.

Has anyone been confronted to this problem and how do we solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Found the solution:

Remove the indexes before you rebuild. (Or the invalid segment will be used for the next index change and you will see the error above)

They're located under the following directory : *YourinstalledDirectory*\liferay-portal-6.0.6\data\lucene and delete all the directories and files. Make sure the server is stopped before doing this.